Reduce white space and intuitive interaction
The following is a modal where you select information and click download to download a file.
This is on a webpage.
Works fine. But design wise, finding too much white space created due to the height increase coming from the checkbox section.
(I mean too much white space under the dates).
Also not sure if the design is intuitive enough. Like should I add more details about each of the date section.
Essentially 2 dates, and report does some comparison between these 2 dates.
Does the title "Select Two Dates To Generate A Report" explains it to you already.
Not really a fan of the title "Select Two Dates To Generate A Report".
Would have preferred not to have any title there and just let the modal be intuitive and understandable.
But without that explanation, not sure a user understands what they need to do.
I can design this modal anyway I want.
I do need the checkbox selectors, the select market dropdown, the 2 date selectors and download button.
Anyway to redesign this to make it more compact and intuitive.
Appreciate any feedbacks. Thank you.


I think the final design depends on the need of the project. In terms, I would recommend a study of everything that needs to be included and try to simplify:

"Select" is repeated unnecessarily three times
The date selection option is on the right while the "market" and "devices" options are on the left.



This addresses my concerns. Only bit that doesn't fit are the labels for the dates. Is not a range between 2 dates. Is more a choice of 2 dates and comparing them. Thus From: and To: doesn't really fit. Something like Initial Date:  Comparison Date: or, Primary Date: Secondary Date:  might fit though feel not truly descriptive.
